# Erro no Sequelize db:migrate

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize-js

Olá!
Tenho um DB Postgres rodando perfeitamente na minha máquina.
Eu consigo criar as minhas migrations, como por exemplo no seguinte comando:

```
npx sequelize migration:create --name=create-users
```

Estou tentando executar um migrate, porém está retornando o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código da migration:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('users', { 
        id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            primatyKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true,
            allowNull: false
        },
        name: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        email: {
            type: Selection.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        password: {
            type: Selection.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        created_at: {
            type: Sequelize.DATE,
            allowNull: false
        },
        updated_at: {
            type: Selection.DATE,
            allowNull: false
        }
    });
},
down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        return queryInterface.dropTable('users');
}
```

};

Alguém tem ideia do que eu estou fazendo errado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está identificando o `type` como `Selection`, o correto é `Sequelize`

Exemplo:

```js
return queryInterface.createTable('users', { 
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primatyKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false
    },
    name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    password: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    created_at: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: false
    },
    updated_at: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: false
    }
});
```

Veja os tipos disponíveis na [documentação](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-basics.html#data-types).

Comment: Putz... Obrigado Rafael Tavares. Falta de atenção minha. Valeu!